# Github action is not running after publishing a release

Tags: git, github, cicd

I have a workflow that should run after publishing a release on github

```
name: Release Notification

on:
  release:
    types:
      - published

jobs:
  Send_Notification:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Print Release
        run: echo Release Published
```

I tested this action on multiple repositories and it is working very well after each release it will run , except one repository and I don't know why

I tried to change the **on** listener to multiple form like

```
on:
  release:
    types:
      - published
    branch: [ master ]
```

and

```
on:
  release:
    types:[ published ]
    branch: [ master ]
```

but both of them didn't work at all on the repository (note that my main branch called **master** in this repo)
my question is:

- Is there any permission for this action to run ?
- Does the creator of the github Action should be the owner of the repo ?

Thanks

***UPDATE MESSSAGE***

It worked on the repository but to a recent tag , I put and new tag on an old commit and published a release, but it didn't run at all !!